# How to add some margin to each link created in sidenavigation (WordPress)

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

You'll see a navigation called "of interest" in the right. I want to add some margin to each link. Currently, I'm doing this horrible(!)thing in the style.css:

```
li#menu-item-20, li#menu-item-31, li#menu-item-73, li#menu-item-74, 
li#menu-item-75, li#menu-item-76, li#menu-item-77, li#menu-item-78, li#menu-item-79 
{margin-top: 15px;}
```

Horrible, but it works. How do it the right way? The links are created via a custom menu ("appearance/menu") in the back-end.

Link: http://new.shiva-rahbaran.org/wordpress/
Template: Twenty-Twelve

Best,
Amir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#menu-side-menu li{
   margin-top: 15px;
}
```

Comment: this will ensure all the li elements from the side menu are being targeted

Comment: Thx! I still have 2 questions:

How can I found out myself the next time?
Why do all 3 suggestions work here? Which one to choose?

Thx :)

Comment: the # targets the id attribute and the . targets any class attribute. the reason they all work its because they all eventually point to the same thing

Comment: the only difference with my answer is that its not looking for the class menu-item it simply targets all li elements which is under #menu-side. i think its best if you learn CSS its very easy go to http://codecademy.com very good place for beginners!

Comment: Thx, again. Actually finished CSS codecademy. Guess it was too much info and I need more practice. Had troubles although using the great "Elements" tool from Chrome. You helped me a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

You could take the id of the column and apply the style to every item of the class menu-item like this:

```
#secondary .menu-item {
    margin-top: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
div#secondary ul.menu li.menu-item {
    margin-top: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Even though code-only answers are valid, it is far better to add at least some sort of comment saying why this works and what was wrong with what the OP tried.